# Cancel Task in await recent method C#

Tags: c#, task

I would like to cancel a Task.run in a clean and simple way here is my code:

```
bool NTAG_isHere = false;

// CODE (...)

private async Task Dump_NTAG(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    // while NTAG PRESENT DUMP START:
    await Task.Run(() => {while (NTAG_isHere()) { } });

    // CODE (...)

    // If NTAG NOT PRESENT or not detected stop the dump and kill thread:
    if(!NTAG_isHere)
    {
      // kill the thread
    }

{
```

Thank you,

Edit 4, my complete method :

```
    private void Dump_NTAG(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        try
        {
            richTextBox_debug.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(CleanText), new object[] {string.Empty});


            WriteLine(NTAG_isHere());

            if (!NTAG_isHere())
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    richTextBox_debug.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(CleanText), new object[] { string.Empty });
                    byte[] dump = new byte[540];
                    int i;
                    richTextBox_debug.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(UpdateText), new object[] { "START" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine });
                    for (i = 0; i < 135; i++)
                    {
                        string Result = arduino.SendCommand("/READ " + i);
                        string[] SplitResult = Result.Split('/', ' ');

                        if (SplitResult.Length > 1)
                        {
                            if (Result.Split('/', ' ')[1] == "ERROR")
                                richTextBox_debug.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(UpdateText), new object[] { string.Format("NFC_Error" + Result.Substring(1) + Environment.NewLine) });

                            else
                                richTextBox_debug.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(UpdateText), new object[] { string.Format("NFC_Unknown_Response" + Result + Environment.NewLine) });

                            i = 135;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string page = "Page";
                            richTextBox_debug.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(UpdateText), new object[] { string.Format(page + " {0} : {1}", i, Result) + Environment.NewLine });
                        }
                    }

                    if (i == 135) { richTextBox_debug.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(UpdateText), new object[] { "Dump success !" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine });  }

                    arduino.SendCommand("/NTAG_HALT");
                    arduino.Close();
                });
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR !!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

my concern is that i can no longer dump, the boolean would still be wrong with this new code, but my method NTAG_isHere () returns good value, so is not in question. and that never do I pass in MessageBox.Show ("ERROR !!"); with or without ntag on the player

Comment: how are you planing to cancel a Task that is already done? Start with puttin await after everything else. And in this case all you need to do is to set NTAG to false.

Answer (score 0):

looking at your code now , you can simply do this , there is no need of cancellation thing , just check the method `returns true` than run task else dont

```
   private void Read_amiibo(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
         bool ishere = NTAG_isHere();
        //store reference of local thread 
        if(ishere)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
              //do operation
            }
        }
        else {
         //exit
        }
    }
```

---

**one point to add her**e :  if you make use of async/await your call get return when await encounters and code below will not get executed

Below solution will work in case when there is no async/await

---

make use of [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation) with task that will do for you, CancellationToken you can pass as argument to run method and monitor it for cancellation.

This is cleaner way given by Microsoft team.

```
 var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
 var token = tokenSource.Token;
 var t = Task.Run( () => { 
              //perform task 
             if (token.IsCancellationRequested) 
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
               }    , token);

  if(!NTAG_isHere)
   {
     // kill the thread
     tokenSource.Cancel();
  }
```

---

other way not much recommended ,

```
        //store reference of local thread 
        Thread threadToCancel = null;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            //Capture the thread
            threadToCancel = Thread.CurrentThread;
        }

        //you can put timer also , means check value after some time to avoid while loop 
         while(true) {
           if(NTAG_isHere){
             threadToCancel.Abort();
          } 
        }
```

Discussed this approach here : [Abort/Cancel Task](http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2017/12/abortcancel-task.html)

reference check here : [`Task.Run Method (Action, CancellationToken)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160373(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @yave - edit cause problem to link ...but its updated now ..you can visit this link : http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2017/12/abortcancel-task.html which is also updated in answer

Comment: sorry but I do not understand what signature uses for my private async method Task Dump_NTAG (object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)

Comment: @yave-- dont make use of await , if you use that then next statment will not get executed

Comment: @yave- if you make use of async/await your call get return when await encounters and code below will not get executed

Comment: @yave - thre is issue , you have to do like this `threadToCancel = Thread.CurrentThread; while (!NTAG_isHere()) { }`..means change order of statement , getting reference to current thread must come first than the while loop

Comment: @yave - NTAG_isHere() is method and what it does

Comment: @yave - updated my answer that should work for you because you dont need to do dirty stuff of cancellation task, first just get from method and based on that start thread or not

Comment: @yave - if you do this await Task.Run(() => {while (!NTAG_isHere()) { } }); than your below code get exeucte after you come out of task ...means when task get complete